# Kibana timelion dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Created an index student and loaded json data. sample json data :

```
{
  "name": "Daniel",
  "joiningdate": "06-28-2018",
  "street": "mark street",
  "city":"sj"  
} 
_mapping
{
 .....
  "properties":{ "joiningdate":{"type":"date","format":"mm-dd-yyyy"}}..
}
```

while ploting timelion graph with count, it is showing empty record. any idea

Comment: Your date format should be `MM-dd-yyyy` as `mm` stands for minutes, not months. You also need to make sure to create an index pattern for your index.

Comment: @Val. But i couldn;t mark it as tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format should be `MM-dd-yyyy` as `mm` stands for minutes, not months. You also need to make sure to create an index pattern for your index.

```
"properties":{ "joiningdate":{"type":"date","format":"MM-dd-yyyy"}}..
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                                                 change this
```

Comment: Any solution on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183987/kibana-6-3-0-share-saved-dashboard-short-dashboard