# Kibana 6.3.0 - "Share saved dashboard" - short dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5

How to get short url for "Share saved dashboard" options. Now it is giving some very lengthy url . it is very tough to share the url. kibana have build in option for "Share Snapshot" not for Saved dashboard. any solution

Comment: @val . any idea on this

Comment: The easiest solution is to copy/paste that URL into an adhoc URL shortener (bit.ly, etc) and use that short link

Comment: adhoc URL shortener -? what does it mean ? can you please provide more information

Comment: Go to https://bitly.com (or find another one by googling "url shortener"), paste your dashboard link, and generate a short link from it

Comment: How can do it for this url : http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/fbb038d0-8071-11e8-97f0-55ef54ac6028?_g=()

Comment: That URL is not that long :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174441/discussion-between-learn-hadoop-and-val).